# OSX disable wake on USB

Tags: macos, usb, sleep-wake

Recently I've obtained a trackball, and I'm trying to use it with my Mac Mini running 10.9.5. The trackball is plugged in via USB port. The ball is rather sensitive, so it picks up very small movement, like from vibration of the desk.

So when I put my computer to sleep, quite often it wakes up from that movement. Sometimes I'm not even sure there is any movement. The computer just enters the sleep mode, I barely even breathe, and several seconds after the power indicator starts blinking it powers up again.

When I unplug the trackball, everything works fine.

So, is there a way to disable waking Mac from a particular USB device? If not, from USB entirely? Or maybe only pointing device movement (clicks would be alright)?

Comment: Are you sure it is a sleep or just display off, in display off any movement will turn it on again, in sleep you will have to Click to wake it up.

Comment: Well, I can hear the Mini go from noisy to silent, and the power LED goes from constant glow to slow blinking, so I figure it is a proper sleep.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick google it seems you are out of luck.

The basic reasoning is that you (normally) would want to wake from key or mouse press, and if these are connected via USB then the mac needs to detect activity on the USB, and rather than distinguish between clicks and movements it wakes on both.

Most of apples own mice are bluetooth, and mac os x has an option within the system preferences not to wake mac on bluetooth (either disable on move and click or just movement, I forget which).

Can you pull out the trackball's ball?  Turn it upside down, or you might just have to disconnect it.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, my google showed the same, so I came here to ask. :/ And no, to pull the ball out I have to disassemble the device first. Turning it upside down will only make things worse as it will roll away and down to the floor. And unplugging it each time is a pain I can't live with.

Comment: If no one else has a software solution the you may have to buy a USB hub with a switch? Googling "usb hub with switch" gave a selection